# Regular Expressions to find and replace text

Tags: c#, regex, winforms

I have a string variable and following is the content of it:

> .....
>   DataElement deAbtVersionNum
>   m_AttrParent commercialcardsys::CommercialCardInt
>    m_AttrGUIFieldLabel "WEX_CI 3.02.01P20.1" appsys30::lngDbb
>    m_AttrdbType "char"
>   .....

As the ... indicates, there maybe other text also.

In the third line we have "WEX_CI 3.02.01P20.1" (This is the only place starting from bottom where WEX.. is present.)

I need to replace 3.02.01P20.1(entirely) with a new version say 3.02.01P20.1.NEW

I have been able to do it using a dirty method which looks for the index of "Wex and then finds the next " and blah blah.

```
                int start = CItext.LastIndexOf("\"WEX") + 1;
                int end = CItext.IndexOf("\"", start);
                string text = CItext.Substring(start, end - start + 1);

                string[] parts = text.Split(new Char[] { ' ' });
                string editedText = parts[0] + " " + LabelName;
                CItext = CItext.Replace(text, editedText);
```

CIText is the string that I have to edit.
LabelName is the string I want to put instead of 3.02.01P20.1

Can anyone suggest me any other clean method ?

Comment: What makes you think the existing logic is dirty and regex clean?

Comment: Coz its too many lines. I welcome other methods, not necessarily regex

Comment: with [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) you don't need regex. Would that work?

Comment: @AkshayJ Can you show the "too many lines"? We can start from there.

Comment: @AkshayJ Where do you change the version?

Comment: I think what you have now is ok. Moving this logic into a properly named function would also help you in the future if you will change the replace implementation. How is the string generated anyway? It looks like a definition file. Maybe you can change the version at that point.

Comment: @Default, yes it work work but I dont know what follows WEX_CI. It can be WEX_CI 12345 or even WEX_CI abcde. I want them changes to WEX_CI NEW_VERSION

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This Regex

```
var result =   Regex.Replace(text,@"(WEX_CI[\s][\da-zA-Z\.]+)","$1.NEW");
```

Comment: Are you adding .NEW to 3.02.01P20.1 ? I just want to replace entire 3.02.01P20.1 by 3.02.01P20.1.NEW. Please update

Comment: No I am not replacing...but using this code first it find WEX_CI and then replace content after it with $1 means 3.02.01P20.1 replaced with 3.02.01P20.1.NEW .you can check at [link](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a regex with "lookahead". Try this.

```
var result = Regex.Replace(text, "(?<=WEX_CI )[^\"]+", "NEW", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Comment: I want "WEX_CI<space>WHATEVER" to "WEX_CI<space>NEW", will your implementation do it ? Even the inverted commas are there.

Comment: Your solution didnt work. Have you taken care of the text that appears before "WEX_CI.. ?